# what subset $y$ of the set $N_0$ define the relations $\{ 3,5 \} \subseteq y \subseteq \{1,3,5,7 \}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

what subsets $y$ of the set $N_0$ define the relations $\{ 3,5 \} \subseteq y \subseteq \{1,3,5,7 \}$?

what sets $y$ define the relation $y \subseteq \{a \}$ where $\{a \}$ is a given single set?

Could anyone give some hints and ideas for finding this subsets?

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  review the definition.  Subset or equal $(\subseteq)$ means that all the elements of the set on the left are also elements of the set on the right.  The set on the right may have additional elements as well.  You have two numbers that must be in $y$ and some others that are optional.  Can you identify those?

Comment: its the $N without 1,3,5,7$?

Comment: No.  If $8$ is an element of $y$, you will not have the right subseteq relation holding.

Comment: 1,3,5,7 and 3,5 then?

Comment: Getting closer, but there are two more

Comment: 1,3,5 and 3,5,7?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: we have 4 subsets. and for the second one is every single set of N?

Comment: No. All the elements of $y$ must be elements of $\{a\}=A$. If $A$ has four elements, there will be $2^4=16$ subsets, as each element can be in or out of a given subset

Comment: yea but {a} we mean a set with one elemnt only

Comment: Then the only subsets are the empty set and $\{a\}$.  The usual term is a "singleton" set.

Comment: and something last, what subset of $y$ of the set $G=\{x /xis a letter the English alphabeta \}$ define the relations $\{a,b\} \subseteq y \subseteq \{b,a \}$? maybe is a singleton set?

Comment: The order of elements in a set doesn't matter.  In this case $y$ has to include $a$ and $b$ from the left inclusion and cannot include anything else from the right inclusion.  So $y=\{a,b\}$

Comment: but if $G=g$? what could be the y

Comment: $G$ has $26$ elements, all the letters.  Here you are using what is often called set-builder notation (though your slash would usually be $|$).  It says $G$ consists of all $x$ such that $x$ is a letter (though the reuse of $x$ might be confusing, I would use $\alpha$ or some such).  Then when you say $y$ is a subset of $G$, you are saying that all the elements of $y$ are letters.  Given your last, you don't need that at all.  Once you have $\{a,b\} \subseteq y \subseteq \{b,a \}$ you have specified $y$ completely.

Comment: i thought that the set $G$ has only one element and this element would be any letter of the English alphabeta

Comment: No, that is not the way set-builder works.  Another definition would be $H=\{x|1 \le x \le 10\}$, which is another way of saying $H=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$  The set includes all the things that satisfy the condition.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help now it's clear